# Batch rename functions knowing their prototypes in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, idapython, functions

I have a long list of mappings from IDA function names (`sub_??????`) to known function prototypes. The prototype is complete, I mean it contains the return type, the name as in the code and the argument types and names.

My question is, how can I batch rename and overwrite all the data about the functions with this prototype information using an IDAPython script?

Comment: Sometimes IDA can't detect function parameters from stack (like __fastcall). So you have to determine the numbers of prameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDA has the [`idc.SetType`](https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/29ec1ceba20cc5c9c7139300e93befb3a3d18b1b/python/idc.py#L5236) method that would accept a function start offset and a function prototype string and will set that function's prototype, although it will not set the function's name.

The `idc.SetType` function is actually a convenience function around `ida_typeinf.idc_parse_decl` and `ida_typeinf.apply_type`, through a couple of other methods defined in the `idc` module. If you wanna set both function name and prototype, you could use `idc.parse_decl` to parse the prototype and then call `idc.apply_type` and `idc.set_name` to set the prototype and name.

Reading the code I linked to around `idc.SetType` really makes the API clear.

An example code could look something like this:

```
prototype_details = idc.parse_decl(PROTOTYPE, idc.PT_SILENT)
if prototype_details:
    idc.set_name(FUNCTION_ADDRESS, prototype_details[0])
    idc.apply_type(FUNCTION_ADDRESS, prototype_details)
```

Naturally, you'll need to replace `PROTOTYPE` and `FUNCTION_ADDRESS` with the function's prototype and address, as well as implement this inside a loop. I'll leave this an an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This is probably not enough. All types used in function prototypes (structure pointers, for example) should be imported too, either with import header file or by creating corresponding structures, otherwise setting prototype will fail.

Comment: Yes. Of course. I didn't address auxiliary structures because OP didn't mention any but you're obviously right.

Answer (score 0):

use [idc.SetType](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.SetType) to `change type`

##### Example

```py
import idc

funcAddr = 0x1024D0000
print("funcAddr=0x%X" % funcAddr)
oldFuncType = idc.get_type(funcAddr)
print("oldFuncType=%s" % oldFuncType)

newFuncType = "id objc_msgSend_arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray__1024D0000(id curObj, const char * arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray_, id someArray)"
print("newFuncType=%s" % newFuncType)
setTypeRet = idc.SetType(funcAddr, newFuncType)
print("setTypeRet=%s" % setTypeRet)
if setTypeRet == 1:
  print("SetType OK [0x%X] %s -> %s" % (funcAddr, oldFuncType, newFuncType))
else:
  print("! SetType failed [0x%X] %s -> %s" % (funcAddr, oldFuncType, newFuncType))
```

output:

```bash
oldFuncType=id(void *, const char *, ...)

setTypeRet=True
SetType OK [0x1024D0000] id(void *, const char *, ...) -> id objc_msgSend_arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray__1024D0000(id curObj, const char * arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray_, id someArray)
```